Algorithm for finding elements within a list
I am looking for an algorithm, I don't know if it exists, that will help me with my following problem:
I have a list of N numerical elements, from that list, I need to find X elements that add up to give me an exact value (this value is always possible to find).
Example:
N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
X = 4 
Value_sought = 27 
Solution = [4,6,8,9]
From my list N I take 4 values ​​that add up to give me 27.
I tried Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), but I couldn't adapt it to my problem

Look into the Subset Sum Problem

I closed this as a duplicate. Note that the accepted answer to that question is very inefficient compared to my answer. Also note that it finds all of the subsets that work, rather than just one - but that's OK, you can discard the rest.
